# Eclipse javascript code being changed

Tags: eclipse

I have this situation with eclipse , whenever I formated the js script of table ,sometimes  eclipse changed the code and sometime much complex when there is no backup.

original Code:

```
    if (isEdit == true) {
            positionSpanTag = "<span class='position input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-lock'></i>";
            meberSpanTag = "<span class='memberName input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-lock'></i>";
        } else {
            positionSpanTag = "<span class='position input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-search'></i>";
            meberSpanTag = "<span class='memberName input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-search'></i>";
        }

        var deleteButton = "<a style='cursor:pointer' class='btn-fab-mini' id='btnRemove'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>";
        var inputHiddenTag = "<input  type='hidden'>";
        var inputTag = "<input  type='text' class='form-control' style='width: 180px;'>";

        var spanCalenderTag = "<span class='input-group-addon '><i class='fa fa-calendar' aria-hidden='true'></i></span>";
```

After, eclipse changed itself:

```
            if (isEdit == true) {
            positionSpanTag = "_$tag_____________________________________$tag__________________$ta";
            meberSpanTag = "_$tag_______________________________________$tag__________________$ta";
        } else {
            positionSpanTag = "_$tag_____________________________________$tag____________________$ta";
            meberSpanTag = "_$tag_______________________________________$tag____________________$ta";
        }

        var deleteButton = "_$tag__________________________________________________________$tag___________________$ta_$ta";
        var inputHiddenTag = "_$tag_________________";
        var inputTag = "_$tag__________________________________________________________";

        var spanCalenderTag = "_$tag_____________________________$tag_________________________________________$ta_$tag__";
```

I have submitted the bug report on this [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=535293).

Comment: That doesn't look like Eclipse. Which plug-ins have you installed?

Comment: @howlger, it is eclipse. it is Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200 and i did not installed any additional flug-ins

Comment: Is this really plain Eclipse without additional plug-ins? Which package and which version? How can the problem be reproduced?

Comment: @howlger, Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) Build id: 20180405-1200. It is occasionally but it definitely change like that. I also have same problem with eclipse mars before.

Comment: It looks like [Eclipse bug 319855](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=319855), but this bug was fixed many years ago. Strange.

Comment: yes, exactly , now it isn't fixed for sure.

Comment: Sure. I have no idea if something can be turned off as a workaround. You might try it with a new workspace. No matter you get an answer or not here, please report it to Eclipse.

Comment: ok , i will report

Comment: @Downvoter , help me if have a idea.

Comment: Thanks for reporting (please add the bug number here). I hope someone can answer this question.